# How to represent many-to-many selection in MVC3 View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, many-to-many

In my model, I have an Product object, I have an Author object and they have a many-to-many relationship, so I have a ProductAuthor object as well.
Functionally, I want a textbox in my view, where the user can enter an author's name, I'll search for it (using Ajax), and display a few results underneath, then the user can click to add one (or more), and the selected ones are displayed next to this search box. Then, when I press Save on my form, everything gets saved (in the controller), not before (so no async AddAuthor method).
Also, if I load up a Product to edit, and it already has authors attached, I want them to be displayed, and the user must be able to unselect them (so when he presses save, they'll no longer be connected.)

How do I represent it in the View? It's ok if I have to write a foreach loop on display, but on submit how will they get sent? Do I generated hidden fields for every selected author? If so, how do I name them, so I can access them in controller? Can they somehow be serialized into typed entities, or will I have to look them up in the FormCollection?

Bonus point if I can use the same thing with very little change for a one-to-many relation (when an article can only have one author, but I don't want to use dropdownlist for that, since there can be many authors, and it wouldn't be searchable, and if I write an async FindAuthor for the many-to-many scenario, I'd like to use it in the one-to-many as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of product edit, there will be multiple authors which you want to select, so you can store in *hidden* field. Multiple hidden fields are not necessary. just append the author IDs

```
<input id="authorIDs" type="hidden" value="56,64,33" />
```

you can use *FormCollection* or *Typed Entity* to get this data.

Comment: So, what you're saying, is modify the value of this hidden field using JS during selection and unselection, post it as one value. But: how do I get it using typed entity? My product entity has a ProductAuthors navigational property, and nothing else to do with authors really. Do I extend it with partial class? Or do I use a ViewModel class instead?

Comment: also, if I give my model/viewmodel class an AuthorIDs property, do I make it a string? or can I use int[]?

Comment: Use ViewModel, and declare it as a string. MVC currently has no support to automatically bind to a property int[] in Model binder class